# Is it possible to reuse service definitions across multiple docker-compose files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have `docker-compose-dev.yaml, docker-compose-staging.yaml, docker-compose-prod.yaml`
We would like to refactor some of the service definitions inside `docker-compose-common.yaml`, so rest of the lifecycle specific definitions can inherit.

Is it possible to reuse service definitions across multiple docker-compose files, in the above fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, please check the official documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).
The file containing the common definitions must be named docker-compose.yml, for the overrides you can keep the names you already use (-dev, -staging, etc.).
Just make sure you use the -f parameter when running docker compose:

```
 docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml -f docker-compose-prod.yaml up -d
```